# Automatically add files to Bitbucket Server git repositories when they are created?

Tags: git, bitbucket-server

I would like to add a file (readme.md) to a Bitbucket Server git repository when it is created.  I am looking for suggestions on the best way to do this as well as any example code on how to accomplish it.  I was looking at the following possibilities:

1. Git pre/post hook
2. Template file for git -init (Would this work when a user clicks the "Create Repository" in the Bitbucket GUI?)
3. Bitbucket ScriptRunner listener

Thank you for any help!

Working on a script to add the files manually.  Still in progress.

Comment: Did you try any of those options yet? If yes, what was the result?

Answer (score 1):

If you do not mind a commercial app, another option could be our
[Repository Templates for Bitbucket](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1213038/repository-templates-for-bitbucket?hosting=datacenter&tab=overview).

Add common files like `LICENSE.txt` or `CODEOWNERS` to your template
repository, and when you create a new repository, you can choose
that template as a start and all the files will be copied over to the new repository.

Comment: Hello.  Would the plugin clone other plugin settings to the new repo?  Thanks.  Planning to test it soon.

Comment: Yes, it also supports a wide range of settings it can sync to the new repository, e.g. branch permissions or hook settings. Please see the Marketplace listing for a list of supported setting types.